# What is the better option to put text over the image? img src or div style background image url?

Tags: html

What is more used option to put text over image? Does text usually go better with 
 use of ordinary `img src="picture.jpg"` or use div `stlye="background-image: url(picture url);`" ?

I asked this because many poeple use different browsers.

thank you.

Comment: Its Depend on Project condition and requirement

Comment: if your image has fix width height i prefer to use img src otherwise background is a good solution

Comment: i think this will be better div stlye="background-image: url(picture url);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both, both modern browsers and older ones will handle both methods correctly - background images in CSS and `<img>` are old and stable techniques.

Which you should pick, it depends on type of image and and purpose. As a rule of thumb, if it is really an image with meaningful content relevant to the rest of the page, you want it to be downloadable (right click - save image), indexed by search engines or enabled to users with screen readers or other assistive technologies, use `<img>`. Otherwise use background image.

Also, if you need to create some type of schema or diagram that combines image and text, best solution would be to use SVG.